# 500 error POSTing to Django-Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I am using django 1.7 and Tastypie 0.12.0 Whenever I try to POST to django-tastypie, the object is not created and I get a 500 error with this response:

```
{"error_message": "add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Comment", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):

File \"/Users/yapster2/Desktop/backend/FivesDjangoRepo/fives/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 201, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

File \"/Users/yapster2/Desktop/backend/FivesDjangoRepo/fives/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 432, in dispatch_list
return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)

File \"/Users/yapster2/Desktop/backend/FivesDjangoRepo/fives/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 464, in dispatch
response = method(request, **kwargs)

File \"/Users/yapster2/Desktop/backend/FivesDjangoRepo/fives/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1340, in post_list
updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))

File \"/Users/yapster2/Desktop/backend/FivesDjangoRepo/fives/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2104, in obj_create
return self.save(bundle)

File \"/Users/yapster2/Desktop/backend/FivesDjangoRepo/fives/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2247, in save
self.save_related(bundle)

File \"/Users/yapster2/Desktop/backend/FivesDjangoRepo/fives/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2298, in save_related
setattr(related_obj, field_object.related_name, bundle.obj)

File \"/Users/yapster2/Desktop/backend/FivesDjangoRepo/fives/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py\", line 783, in __set__
manager.add(*value)

TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Comment"}
```

I don't want to clutter the post, so let me know if you need to see a specific code.

Here's my model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(NewsFeedPost, related_name='comments', null=True, blank=True)
    comment_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='comments', null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)   
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    hashtags = models.ManyToManyField(Hashtag, related_name='comments', null=True, blank=True)
```

And my resource:

```
class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    post = fields.ForeignKey('newsfeed.api.NewsFeedPostResource', 'post', related_name='comments',
                             null=True, blank=True, full=True)
    comment_by = fields.ForeignKey('login.api.UserResource', 'comment_by', related_name='comments',
                                   null=True, blank=True, full=True)
    hashtags = fields.ManyToManyField('newsfeed.api.HashtagResource', 'hashtag_set',
                                      related_name='comments', null=True, blank=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Comment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'comments'
        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {
            "post": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
```

Comment: Can you post your model in Django and Tastypie. You may have some `related_name`, you can delete in Tastypie.

Comment: Can you give the full stack trace (if there is) also have any idea of exactly which line breaks program. I suspect that there might be a problem with ManyToMany addition.

Comment: Also for `ForeignKey` and `ManyToMany`, why not use `ToOneFields` and `ToManyField`.

Comment: That is the full stack trace. I use ForeignKey because it is slightly different from ToOneField. The reverse of ToOneField only returns one object.